# How to identify in the SQL Server 2005 function is being used in the stored procedure or other objects?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to modify function and I need to know what the impact might be by looking other object that depending on this function such as stored procedure, function etc etc. Now, is there anyway I can find this that can go through all codes? I have a lot of stored procedure/functions on this.

There is possibility within storedproc that have a dynamic constructed query such as @SQL = 'SELECT BLA BLA'

Is there any third party tools that can be used to detect this?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Third Party Tools**

[Redgate SQL Refactor](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_refactor/index.htm) or [Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_Tracker/index.htm) might be best actually.

[Apex SQL Clean](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx)

**Home Made Solutions**

You can use `sp_depends` but this depends on the dependency information being up to date.

Running `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on all objects in the database can update this if there is any missing dependency information.

This won't find places where you have used it in dynamic SQL though. You may be able to track these down with.

```
select object_name(object_id) 
from sys.sql_modules 
where definition like '%Your Function Name%'
```

Assuming that your dynamic SQL string doesn't bizarrely split the function name up.